# Moving an element to another location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector

I want each row's first col content to be moved to its  corresponding third column content. How do I do this? its basically moving the content to its parent's sibling identified by colB class

```
<tr>
<td class="move">
    <div id="move-0">move me 0</div>
</td>
<td class="colA">
    <div>ColA</div>
</td >
<td class="colB">
    <div>ColB</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="move">
    <div id="move-1">move me 1</div>
</td>
<td class="colA">
    <div>ColA</div>
</td >
<td class="colB">
    <div>ColB</div>
</td>
</tr>
...
```

to:

```
<tr>
<td class="move">

</td>
<td class="colA">
    <div>ColA</div>
</td >
<td class="colB">
    <div>ColB</div>
    <div id="move-0">move me 0</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="move">

</td>
<td class="colA">
    <div>ColA</div>
</td >
<td class="colB">
    <div>ColB</div>
    <div id="move-1">move me 1</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('td.move').each(function(){
    var t = jQuery(this);
    t.parent().find('td:last').append(t.children());
});
```

Comment: this worked i revised a couple of selector for flexibility.. .r:last was replaced with td.colB and it worked flawlessly for my requirement. Thanks @J-P

Answer (score 1):

Use **[jQuery.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** and **[jQuery.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)**.